# Conditional calculation based on two columns including Date lag in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe df with columns Date, Inflow and Outflow.  I want to calculate an 'Output' column such that if Input is above 1000 then output should be equal to the sum of 'Outflow' of each of the last three Dates (before the Input>=1000).

```
df<-data.frame(Date=c("2019-05-13 EEST", "2019-05-13 EEST", "2019-05-13 EEST", "2019-05-13 EEST",
                              "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST",
                              "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-11 EEST","2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                              "2019-05-09 EEST", "2019-05-09 EEST", "2019-05-09 EEST", "2019-05-09 EEST",
                              "2019-05-09 EEST"),
                              Inflow=c(0, 0, 0,500, 0,80, 0, 0, 0,38, 0, 0, 0,50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 0,  100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 1400, 0,  100, 0, 0),
                              Outflow= c(-40, -30, -30, 0, -14.35, 0, -66, -28, -10, 0,-50, -50, -3.99,0,
                              -50, -25, -25,-50,-50, -100, -100, -50, -46, -50, -50, 0, -50,-50,-50,-100,
                              -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, 0, -100, 0, -100, -75))
```

The output I need in case of above example numbers would be after detecting the Inflow of 1400 sum each Date lag Outflow amounts separately lag1 Outflow=-50+(-3.99)+0+...+(-100)=-1499; lag2 Outflow=-50; lag3 Outflow=-14.35+0+...+0=-89.65

```
output<- data.frame(Date=c("2019-05-13 EEST","2019-05-13 EEST","2019-05-13 EEST", "2019-05-13 EEST",
                       "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST",
                       "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-12 EEST", "2019-05-11 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST", "2019-05-10 EEST",
                       "2019-05-09 EEST", "2019-05-09 EEST", "2019-05-09 EEST", "2019-05-09 EEST",
                       "2019-05-09 EEST"),Inflow=c(0, 0, 0,500, 0,80, 0, 0, 0,38, 0, 0, 0,50, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 1400, 0, 100,
                         0, 0),
                         Outflow= c(-40, -30, -30, 0, -14.35, 0, -66, -28, -10, 0,-50, -50, -3.99, 0,
                         -50, -25, -25,-50,-50, -100, -100, -50, -46, -50, -50, 0, -50,-50,-50, -100,
                         -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, 0, -100, 0, -100, -75), 
                         Output=c(0,0,0,0,-89.65,-89.65,-89.65,-89.65,-89.65,-89.65,-89.65,-50,
                         -1499,-1499, -1499,-1499,-1499,-1499, -1499,-1499,-1499, -1499,-1499,-1499,
                         -1499,-1499,-1499, -1499,-1499,-1499,-1499, -1499,-1499, -1499,-1499,-1499,
                         -1499,0,0,0,0))
```

**Expected output is:**

```
 output
```

> ```
>    Date              Inflow Outflow Output
> 1  2019-05-13 EEST      0  -40.00     0.00
> 2  2019-05-13 EEST      0  -30.00     0.00
> 3  2019-05-13 EEST      0  -30.00     0.00
> 4  2019-05-13 EEST    500    0.00     0.00
> 5  2019-05-12 EEST      0  -14.35   -89.65
> 6  2019-05-12 EEST     80    0.00   -89.65
> 7  2019-05-12 EEST      0  -66.00   -89.65
> 8  2019-05-12 EEST      0  -28.00   -89.65
> 9  2019-05-12 EEST      0  -10.00   -89.65
> 10 2019-05-12 EEST     38    0.00   -89.65
> 11 2019-05-11 EEST      0  -50.00   -89.65
> 12 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00   -50.00
> 13 2019-05-10 EEST      0   -3.99 -1499.00
> 14 2019-05-10 EEST     50    0.00 -1499.00
> 15 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 16 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -25.00 -1499.00
> 17 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -25.00 -1499.00
> 18 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 19 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 20 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 21 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 22 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 23 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -46.00 -1499.00
> 24 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 25 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 26 2019-05-10 EEST    100    0.00 -1499.00
> 27 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 28 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 29 2019-05-10 EEST      0  -50.00 -1499.00
> 30 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 31 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 32 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 33 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 34 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 35 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 36 2019-05-10 EEST      0 -100.00 -1499.00
> 37 2019-05-09 EEST   1400    0.00 -1499.00
> 38 2019-05-09 EEST      0 -100.00     0.00
> 39 2019-05-09 EEST    100    0.00     0.00
> 40 2019-05-09 EEST      0 -100.00     0.00
> 41 2019-05-09 EEST      0  -75.00     0.00
> ```

I know how to perform conditional calculations with dplyr with one conditional column, but didn't figured it out for two columns with lag. Will appreciate your help!